# Different interval of y-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, gam

I want to plot the maps resulting from a Generalised Additive Model analysis. I have no problem getting them but I would like to to bring the Y-axis a little more to my liking defining two different intervals. I am aware that it can be done manually as in the code I´m using:

```
spplot(FinalSPDF_Pres[,c(1:22)],
      col.regions= mypalette, zcol=c(1:22), names.attr=Uniq_Year,
      at=c(seq(0, 15, 1), 20,25,30,35,40), par.settings =   list(strip.background=list(col="transparent"),
      strip.border=list(col="transparent"), axis.line=list(col="transparent")))
```

In this case, the maximum value is 40, but in other cases the range will be quite wider. I would like to know if it is possible to define another sequence after `seq(0, 15, 1)`.
That is to say, is it possible, for example, something like this `at=c(seq(0, 15, 1)& c(seq(15, 40, 2.5)`?

Comment: Where is `spplot` from? Please include packages that you use in this example.